# Append image to FormData, "stream.on is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm trying to append an image into a form-data.
When I call the function append, I have the error "stream.on is not a function".

HTML:

```
<input id="432bb3b4-dbef-4591-89eb-5e8fd3ff7174_field_0" data-bind="event: { change: function() { uploadImage($element.files[0]) } }" type="file">
```

JavaScript:

```
ViewModel.prototype.uploadImage = function (file) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('filed', file);
};
```

I know there are other post about use FormData, but no one had experienced this error.

Comment: just a quick guess: 'you have a typo filed=>files' ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that should be just the name of the field. So it's not important what I put there

Comment: Yes, you're right, just checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out my mistake.
I used `require("form-data")` in my script and that generated the error. To use FormData in the client, it is not necessary to specify any "require".